# How to convert vararg to list?

Tags: generics, kotlin, variadic-functions

I have a function with a vararg parameter. This vararg parameter needs to be passed to another function as a list.

How do I convert the vararg param into a list? `listOf()` gave me an error.

```
fun insertMissingEntities(vararg entities: Entity) {
  val list = listOf(entities)
  passMissingEntities(list) // Type mismatch. 
                            // Required: List<Entity>
                            // Found: List<Array<out Entity>>
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the extension function `.asList()`, which does no added copying (unlike `listOf` with the spread operator).

```
fun insertMissingEntities(vararg entities: Entity) {
  passMissingEntities(entities.asList())
}
```

Comment: This really is the simpler solution.

Comment: It is `toList()` not `asList`

Comment: @notes-jj: Those are two different things, and I meant `asList()`.  I did *not* mean `toList`.

Answer (score 7):

The vararg param needs to be spread with the spread `*` operator.

```
fun insertMissingEntities(vararg entities: Entity) {
  val list = listOf(*entities)
  passMissingEntities(list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Koltin** (varang a:Entity) ~= **Java** (a:Entity ... a)

Which means the you can pass **multiple params of type Entity** not the entire array/list

When we call a vararg-function, we can pass arguments one-by-one, e.g. asList(1, 2, 3), or, if we already have an array and want to pass its contents to the function, we use the spread operator . (prefix the array with *):

```
    fun insertMissingEntities(vararg entities: Entity) {
      val list = listOf(entities)  // Here entities is already a list of entity so you are doing listOf(listOf(entity)).. Hence , the error

//passMissingEntities(list) -> WRONG// Type mismatch. 
                                    // Required: List<Entity>
                                    // Found: List<Array<out Entity>>


 passMissingEntities(entities) // Just pass the entities instead of converting it to list again
    }
```

Also read : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs